# how to check if function parameter is optional using anzlyzer package?

Tags: dart, analyzer, dart-analyzer

how to check if function parameter is optional using [anzlyzer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) package?

For example:

```
myFunction(param1, {param2});
```

I would like to know that `param1` is required and `param2` is optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters, if I remember correctly, have a `kind` getter, which is an instance of [ParameterKind](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.29.5/analyzer/ParameterKind-class.html), which can be `REQUIRED`, `NAMED` or `POSITIONAL` (also optional).

Comment: for constructor parameters `parameter.kind` always returns parameter

Comment: sorry, it should be `parameter.parameterKind`